# python concatenate .txt/list 2 file in one new file

Tags: python, selenium, concatenation

I would like to know how it possible to concatenate 2 text file into one file an example will be clearer:

I have text file 'result_name' with the name of the processor written on it

and another text file 'resultat_prix with the price written above 169 euros

I would like to know how to have a text file 'total result' with written above the name of the processor + the price next to it example: Intel Core i5-10400F (2.9 GHz / 4.3 GHz) 169 € 96

Attached is the photo of the two lists  [image]

and my code doesnt look like i want :

> filenames = ['resultat_nom.txt', 'resultat_prix.txt']
> with open('resultat_total.txt', 'w') as outfile:
> for fname in filenames:
> with open(fname) as infile:
> outfile.write(infile.read())

the final result is : [image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have 2 files: `list1.txt` and `list2.txt` like below:

list1.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

list2.txt

```
A A A
B B B
C C C
D D D
E E E
```

Then, you can "concatenate" them by the following script:

```py
file = open('list1.txt', 'r')
data1 = [item.rstrip() for item in file.readlines()]
file.close()
file = open('list2.txt', 'r')
data2 = [item.rstrip() for item in file.readlines()]
file.close()
file = open('list3.txt', 'w')
for i in range(len(data1)):
    file.write(data1[i]+'\t'+data2[i]+'\n')
file.close()
```

Finally, you get a file `list3.txt` like below:

```
1   A A A
2   B B B
3   C C C
4   D D D
5   E E E
```

Comment: Okay, you can label it as the right answer to help the other viewers.